# Problem in overwriting Application.persistentDataPath

Tags: c#, android, ios, unity-game-engine

I have a JSON file which contains data for my Localization in my game. The file is stored in `Application.persistentDataPath` . I read in the documentation that the file is not deleted or overwritten when updating the game. Currently I launch the app and the file is there but when I add more content and send an update to save again, it only has the original content.

But is there a way to update this file when I update the game?
What if in the future I want to add more content to this JSON file, I would have to delete it and upload it again?
Any way to update and overwrite it?

```
private static void Request(string file)
    {
        var loadingRequest = UnityWebRequest.Get(Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, file));
        loadingRequest.SendWebRequest();
        while (!loadingRequest.isDone)
        {
            if (loadingRequest.isNetworkError || loadingRequest.isHttpError)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (loadingRequest.isNetworkError || loadingRequest.isHttpError)
        {
            // Some error happened.
        }
        else
        {
            File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, file), loadingRequest.downloadHandler.data);
        }
    }

    // Loads key from "StreamingAssets/language_data.json" file.
    public static string LoadJson(string key)
    {
        Request("data.json");
        var jsonPath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, jsonFileName);
        using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(jsonPath))
        {
            var N = JSON.Parse(r.ReadToEnd());
            string result = N[GetLanguage()][key];
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you show us your code of how you are trying to update the file? How do you make sure the content is actually updated?

Comment: Yes I just uploaded it

Comment: `// Loads key from "StreamingAssets/language_data.json" file.`, no it doesn't it loads it from `persistentDataPath`  .... your `Request` method rather loads from `streamingAssetsPath` and writes into `peristentDataPath` which looks fine to me  ... where  are these called from? and in which order?

Comment: @derHugo I call LoadJson() and inside LoadJson it calls Request(). In Editor it works perfectly (I just tested) but in iOS it does not update or add to persistentDataPath even though I Allowed Arbitrary Loads. (Which is where I was normally testing from).

Comment: Oh yeah now I see it sorry ^^ just out of interrest ... what if the request fails? you don't catch such case

Comment: @derHugo Also in Editor I just added content to the Json file in StreamingAssets and it did not copy to persistent because it is already there. I would have to delete it.

Comment: From the API for `File.WriteAllBytes` it states that the file will be overwritten if it already existed, though ... what is `jsonFileName`? are you sure it is correct?

Comment: @derHugo I don't understand but maybe it is the `UnityWebRequest` in Request() that is messing with the iOS Transport Security ?

Comment: @derHugo Yes it is "language_data.json"

Comment: `language_data.json` is not the same as `data.json` .. and you are loading and writing with the given file name which is `data.json` ...

Comment: @derHugo same thing happened, the file was copied to persistent like before

Comment: What I am saying is: you are first copying `StreamingAssets/data.json` => `persistentData/data.json` .. then you try to load values from `persistentData/languages_data.json` .. that is a **different path** to a **different file** => It wasn't updated because you are updating/loading the wrong file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is the following:

You are only creating a file named `data.json` **NOT** `languages_data.json`!

In `Request` (you pass in `"data.json"`) you copy

```
Application.streamingAssetsPath, file
```

to

```
 Application.persistentDataPath, file
```

where `file = "data.json"`

Then in `LoadJson` you are trying to load values from

```
Application.persistentDataPath, jsonFileName
```

where - as to your comments - `jsonFileName = "languages_data.json"`

=> **It is a different path!**

In the Editor/on your PC you probably still have an old `languages_data.json` in the persistent data from some time ago. Therefore there is no error but it is also never updated. Delete the `persistent/languages_data.json` on your PC and it will throw a `FileNotFoundException`.

---

To solve this make 100% sure the file names are the same everywhere. The simplest fix code wise would be to simply rather use

```
Request(jsonFileName);
```

and make sure that `jsonFileName` matches the name of your existing file in `StreamingAssets`.

Comment: Yes thank you what a dumb mistake on my part. Fixed and it is updating. The question that was closed is still not being allowed by iOS.